# Passive FTP connection using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, ftp-client, passive-mode

I wrote a batch script to upload files to FTP server. It works fine but I wanted to establish passive connection to the FTP server.

Most of the articles say command line FTP.exe does not have this feature but one blog says using `QUOTE PASV` will set the ftp client to work in passive mode.

I used that command and ran the script, it said its entering passive mode and was able to upload the files.

Could someone confirm this information?

Thanks

Comment: Hi have you got answer? I am stuck at same. Need to send passive ftp from batch file. Please reply soon. Thanks